# Read Value from MutableDictionnary situated in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate, nsmutabledictionary

Im a actually working on an `Objective-C` app,
I have created 3 `NSMutableDictionary` on my `AppDelegate`,I know how to set values in these `NSMutableDictionary` using :

```
[(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]setCentralServTrapDict:CentralServDict];
```

But i dont't know how to read theses values, i already tried this :

```
[(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]valueForKey:@"kCentralServSystemCpuUsage"];
```

And this .. :

```
[(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]CentralServ valueForKey()];
```

How can I access to the values of my `NSMutableDictionary` from anonther class ?

Comment: Is this an ios app or osx app?

Comment: Try: [[(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] centralServTrapDict] valueForKey:@"someKey"];

Comment: Friend if you are new in `Objective-C` why you don't learn basic first. Avoid to ask such a basic question.

Comment: Damn thank you , it work perfectly ;D

Comment: @Mukesh sry if i annoy you but im a student and im in internship in a company, that's why i don't have much type to learn all the tips and tricks that i could use in this langage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, your syntax for accessing the `dictionary` values seems incorrect. For eg:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mutableDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:@"firstValue"];
NSNumber *firstValueVar = mutableDictionary[@"firstValue"];
```